# add percentage of value to a result

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to calculate the percentage from a entered field.The first field will have a static value in the second field the user should enter a percentage value and this code should get the first value(static) calculate the percentage entered by the user according to the first static value  and add that final value to the final result that is total.Here is some of the code i done but this is just basically adding two numbers whereas i want to add the percentage of second field entered by the user to the first one and display it in the final total title

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input style="max-width: 100px; type="number" min="0" type="text" id="quantity1" value="100" />
<input style="max-width: 100px; type="number" min="0" type="text" id="quantity2" />

<h5 class="total" id="total" value="$123"></h5>

</body>
<script>
$('#quantity2').on('keyup',function(){

    var val=$('#quantity1').val();
    alert(val);
    //alert(val);
    var tot = +$(this).val()+ +$('#quantity1').val() ;
    alert(tot);
    $('.total').html("$"+tot);
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: ummm sorry for the confusion this is my initial experiences in stack overflow i will get use to it.the question is up there

Comment: @AndrewL. I think that's for casting the string values to numbers ( the preceding `+` signs ).

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try editing the question so we can help you :)

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Makes sense, although some whitespace would've cleared the confusion

Comment: looks better now? my bad i haven't actually explained the relation between the question and the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('#quantity2').on('change',function(){ // use .change() event instead of keyup
    var val1 = parseInt($('#quantity1').val()); // use parseInt() to convert string to integer value
    var val2 = parseInt($(this).val());
    var tot = val1 + (val1 * (val2 / 100)); // it will add percentage value to first value
    console.log(tot);
    $('.total').html("$"+tot);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="max-width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" type="text" id="quantity1" value="100" />
<input style="max-width: 100px;" type="number" min="0" type="text" id="quantity2" />

<h5 class="total" id="total" value="$123"></h5>
```

Comment: try? why do i need to try this i am gonna use this..:) thanks man highly appreciated